# Extending the camera vs CameraHelper class vs camera field

Tags: java, libgdx, camera, software-engineering

I am following an eBook called "Learning Libgdx Game Development"

In it, the author implements a `CameraHelper` class that implements `Zoom`, target-following behaviour, and probably some other things along the way.

Can I do this just by extending the camera class, or using composition?

Approaching it like this seems like a clearer code to me:

```
public class Camera extends OrthographicCamera {
    GameObject target;
    boolean followTarget;

    Camera(float viewWidth, float viewHeight){
        super(viewWidth, viewHeight);
    }

    public void setTarget(GameObject target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public GameObject getTarget() {
        return target;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(){
        if(followTarget && target != null){
            this.position.x = target.position.x;
            this.position.y = target.position.y;
        }
        update(true);
    }
}
```

Any problems with this that I can expect?

Comment: You don't need to ask us for permission to write code that you personally find clearer. If it looks clearer to you, go for it. If you run into a problem along the way, ask about that concrete problem and we can help you find concrete solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. I don't see any extra problems. It is OOP way.

- Camera extends OrthographicCamera -> Camera IS OrthographicCamera
- CameraHelper isn't Camera it Helps to work with camera. This is like lib with commonly used stuff. For example if camera doesn't follow player (no need), you don't use/call method from CameraHelper class.